# Apache Camel: How to print Exception Trace while Unit Testing using CamelTestSupport

Tags: unit-testing, exception, apache-camel, integration, testng

Using Camel-core v2.14.1 and camel-testng v2.14.1

Attempting to Unit Test a basic route.

The RouteBuilder class is named as FileToJmsRB and the Route is configured this way

```
@Override
public void configure() {
     from("file:C:\\camel_folder\\orders")
       .when(fileToJmsConditions.camelFileNameEndingWithXml(this))
            .to("file:C:\\camel_folder\\recieved")
}
```

fileToJmsConditions is a variable that I am failing to inject as Spring Bean.

My Test class extends CamelTestSupport and it overrides createRouteBuilder() as follows

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception{
    return new FileToJmsRB();
}
```

and I configure a method as test.

```
@Test
public void testTextFileMove() throws Exception{
    template.sendBodyAndHeader("file:C:\\camel_folder\\orders"
        , "Hello World"
        , Exchange.FILE_NAME
        , "hello.txt");

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    File target = new File("C:\\camel_folder\\recieved\\hello.txt");
    assertTrue(target.exists(), "File Not Moved");
}
```

On running

```
maven install
```

on the project, **I expect** a Null Pointer Exception with a StackTrace in Console.

However, **observation** no hint of type of Exception Thrown and there is not stacktrace printed. It just says that the test failed but does not prints the type of exception or stacktrace.

```
 Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

However, if I wrap my configure method in FileToJmsRB class with 
    try... Catch...
Only then do I see the NullPointerException thrown and Stack Trace printed.

Is there no other, more elegant way of handling this more elegantly? Because this way I must do try...catch... in every Route Builder class?

Comment: Yeah we can improve camel-test / camel-testng to better report runtime exceptions from the route builder. You are welcome to log a ticket at Apache Camel

Comment: Can you please share the URL where I can log the ticket for Apache Camel ?

Comment: You can find the link to the issue tracker here: http://camel.apache.org/support

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thank You. Created the ticket. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8367

Comment: @ClausIbsen Do you know why the tests run stats say that there were two tests run when I had written only one test method?